# unpredictable HTTPError using Entrez.esearch function from Bio package

Tags: python-3.x, biopython

I am trying to fetch records from PubMed central using [Bio package](https://biopython.org/docs/1.76/api/Bio.html) but after fetching 'some' records it produces this error:

```
request.py:643 in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)

HTTPError: Bad Request
```

This 'some' is sometimes 100 or 10 or even 1. I have tried to add delays between efetch calls. In the code below, the `delay` is 1/2 a second but I tried up to 5 seconds, and nothing improved. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
  database = "pmc"
  query = f"{search_terms}[Title] OR {search_terms}[Abstract]"

  ## search the Entrez database and retrieve the results
  handle = Entrez.esearch(db=database, term=query, retmax=10000, api_key = os.environ['ENTREZ_API_KEY'])
  record = Entrez.read(handle)

  ## get the PMIDs for each result
  pmcids = record["IdList"]
  handle.close()

  for pmcid in pmcids:
      ## retrieve the article's full-text XML from PMC
          print(f"Trying to retrieve XML for PMC{pmcid}")
          handle = Entrez.efetch(db=database,
                                 api_key = os.environ['ENTREZ_API_KEY'],
                                 id=pmcid,
                                 retmode="xml",
                                 max_tries=100)

          xml_record = handle.read()
          handle.close()
          time.sleep(0.5)

          print(f"Trying to retrieve text for PMC{pmcid}")
          handle = Entrez.efetch(db=database,
                                  api_key = os.environ['ENTREZ_API_KEY'],
                                  id=pmcid,
                                  rettype="Medline",
                                  retmode="text",
                                  max_tries=100)
          text_record = Medline.read(handle)
          handle.close()
          time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Are you ensuring that you're respecting the NCBI rate limit? [This](https://biopython.org/docs/1.76/api/Bio.Entrez.html#module-Bio.Entrez) documentation mentions that the max requests with an API key is 10 per second. It also mentions the `sleep_between_tries` option that the `Entrez` module has.

Comment: In the efetch calls I am only asking it to fetch 1 article. If you see my code there is an explicit delay call after every efetch. So I do not see how I am violating NCBI rate limit.

Answer (score 0):

I was not catching the exception correctly. After I imported and used `HTTPError` from  urllib (`from urllib.error import HTTPError`) code is able to catch the error and move on. Also,  in some rare cases it goes into `IncompleteRead: IncompleteRead(0 bytes read)` error. This can be solved by importing IncompleteRead (`from http.client import IncompleteRead`). Here is the updated answer.

```
  for pmcid in pmcids:
      ## retrieve the article's full-text XML from PMC
      try:
          print(f"Trying to retrieve XML for PMC{pmcid}")
          handle = Entrez.efetch(db=database,
                                 api_key = os.environ['ENTREZ_API_KEY'],
                                 id=pmcid,
                                 retmode="xml",
                                 max_tries=100)
          try:
              xml_record = handle.read()
              handle.close()
              time.sleep(0.5)
          except IncompleteRead as r:
              print(f"Incomplete Read of XML for PMC{pmcid}: {r}")
              handle.close()
              time.sleep(0.5)
              continue

      except HTTPError as e:
          print(f"Error retrieving XML for PMC{pmcid}: {e}")
          continue

      try:
          print(f"Trying to retrieve text for PMC{pmcid}")
          handle = Entrez.efetch(db=database,
                                  api_key = os.environ['ENTREZ_API_KEY'],
                                  id=pmcid,
                                  rettype="Medline",
                                  retmode="text",
                                  max_tries=100)

          try:
              text_record = Medline.read(handle)
              handle.close()
              time.sleep(0.5)
          except IncompleteRead as r:
              print(f"Incomplete Read of TEXT for PMC{pmcid}: {r}")
              handle.close()
              time.sleep(0.5)
              continue

      except HTTPError as e:
          print(f"Error retrieving TEXT for PMC{pmcid}: {e}")
          continue
```